# SSOCircle Error 0007 when registering a Service Provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm new to the SAML world and I've been trying to get the Spring SSO demo going, but I'm having trouble registering my demo SP at the SSOCircle site. I keep getting an "Error 0007" message. I defined my entity ID as **urn:test:sheldon:boca** and I was finally able to get that to appear in the metadata, but still no luck. I've attached a screenshot of the metadata I generated in the demo SP:

[image: SP XML]

One of my company's SSO experts has told me that my metadata is valid, so I'm unclear on why I'm unable to use it to register my SP. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Could you attach the metadata in readable form? It looks like a mangled base64 decoding

Comment: Okay, I replaced the XML code insert with a screen shot of it displayed in the browser, but I see that things might be cut off in it. Is there a way I can just attach the XML file directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the signature element from the metadata as described at the web site

> Blockquote
>   An error ocurred. Reason:0007 Signed metadata might cause validation problems. We recommend removal of the signature as the fastest workaround.
>   Blockquote

Reference: [ssocircle-how-to](https://www.ssocircle.com/en/idp-tips-tricks/ssocircle-how-to/)

Comment: Okay, I've taken the Capt. Kirk approach to this situation, i.e., I changed the parameters of the situation to one I could solve more easily, but it does appear that SSOCircle simply won't allow you to register SP metadata that includes a signature. I'm sure if I paid for support, this problem could be solved, but I was able to register this version of the SP metadata with Centrify, so I didn't bother to solve this issue...